# (SQLite vb.net)data binding error sql logic error near "like" syntax error vb.net

Tags: database, vb.net, visual-studio, sqlite, visual-studio-code

I have a problem in this code
I need to search in database SQLite with vb.net
when i run this code its started well but when search i have this message
Error (data binding error sql logic error near "like" syntax error vb.net)
[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P2EQ6.jpg)
my code:

```
Imports System.Data.SQLite

Public Class Form1

    Private dbcomand As String = ""
    Private bindingSrc As BindingSource

    Private dbName As String = "conquest.db3;"
    Private dbPath As String = "D:\conquestdicomserver\data\dbase\" & dbName
    Private conString As String = "Data Source=" & dbPath & "Version=3;New=False;Compress=True;"

    Private connection As New SQLiteConnection(conString)
    Private command As New SQLiteCommand("", connection)

    Private sql As String = ""

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

        connection.Open()

        UpdateDatabiding()

        connection.Close()


    End Sub

    Private Sub UpdateDatabiding(Optional cmd As SQLiteCommand = Nothing)
        ''TODO
        Try
            If cmd Is Nothing Then
                command.CommandText = "SELECT StudyDate,PatientNam,StudyModal,StudyDescr,PatientsAg,PatientID FROM DICOMStudies"
            Else
                command = cmd
            End If

            Dim adapter As New SQLiteDataAdapter(command)
            Dim dataSt As New DataSet()
            adapter.Fill(dataSt, "DICOMStudieList")

            bindingSrc = New BindingSource()
            bindingSrc.DataSource = dataSt.Tables("DICOMStudieList")

            Dim tb As TextBox
            For Each ctr As Control In GroupBox1.Controls
                If TypeOf ctr Is TextBox Then
                    tb = CType(ctr, TextBox)
                    tb.DataBindings.Clear()
                    tb.Text = ""
                End If

            Next


            IDShowTextBox.DataBindings.Add("Text", bindingSrc, "PatientID")
            NameShowTextBox.DataBindings.Add("Text", bindingSrc, "PatientNam")

            DataGridView1.Enabled = True
            DataGridView1.DataSource = bindingSrc
            DataGridView1.AutoResizeColumns(CType(DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.AllCells, DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode))
            DataGridView1.SelectionMode = DataGridViewSelectionMode.FullRowSelect

            DataGridView1.Columns(0).Width = 60
            DisplayPosition()

        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show("Data Binding Error: " & ex.Message.ToString())
        End Try


    End Sub

    Private Sub DisplayPosition()
        PositionLabel1.Text = "Position:  " & bindingSrc.Position + 1 & "/" & bindingSrc.Count
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

        Dim Psi As New ProcessStartInfo
        With Psi
            .FileName = "C:\Program Files\RadiAntViewer64bit\RadiAntViewer.exe"
            .Arguments = "D:\conquestdicomserver\data\" & IDShowTextBox.Text
        End With
        Process.Start(Psi)

    End Sub

    Private Sub SearchButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles SearchButton.Click

        If connection.State = ConnectionState.Closed Then
            connection.Open()
        End If

        Try
            If String.IsNullOrEmpty(KeywordTextBox.Text.Trim()) Then
                UpdateDatabiding()
                Exit Sub
            End If

            sql = "SELECT StudyDate,PatientNam,StudyModal,StudyDescr,PatientsAg,PatientID FROM DICOMStudies"
            sql &= "WHERE PatientNam LIKE @keyword2"


            command.CommandType = CommandType.Text
            command.CommandText = sql
            command.Parameters.Clear()

            Dim KeywordString As String = String.Format("%{0}%", KeywordTextBox.Text)
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@keyword1", KeywordTextBox.Text)
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@keyword2", KeywordString)
            UpdateDatabiding(command)


        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show("Search Error: " & ex.Message.ToString(),
                            "Error Message : iBasskung Tutorial.",
                            MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
        Finally
            connection.Close()
            KeywordTextBox.Focus()
        End Try

    End Sub
End Class
```

when i run this code its started well but when search i have this message
Error (data binding error sql logic error near "like" syntax error vb.net)
[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CSOi4.jpg)

Comment: This is what happens when you don't bother to debug your code. Use the debugger properly, i.e. set a breakpoint, and then look at the actual value of `sql` and the issue should be obvious. If you're told that there's a syntax error in your SQL and you don't look at your SQL then you're ignoring the information right in front of you. This is also an example of why you should generally avoid string concatenation. It shouldn't have been hard to spot the issue but you made your code harder to read and that's why you missed it.

Comment: Tldr: You don't have a space between the table name and WHERE clause.in your SQL string that you missed be sure it's concatenated together and on different lines.

Answer (score 0):

As others sugegsted, we need to give the space before the `where` clause.

Please make the following change:

```
    sql = "SELECT StudyDate,PatientNam,StudyModal,StudyDescr,PatientsAg,PatientID FROM DICOMStudies"
    sql &= " WHERE PatientNam LIKE @keyword2" //-> add a space before WHERE
```